# Can you query an SSMS Central Management Server list without using SSMS, like with a connection string or something similar?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Due to work restrictions, I unfortunately **cannot** use linked servers.

I'm wondering if it's possible to query a Central Management Server list created in SSMS using a connection string or something similar from outside of SSMS. Right now the only way that I can find to query it is to actually have SSMS open, right click inside the CMS and create a new query. Is there a way to create a connection string to this CMS so I can query it from from an application?

Thank you!

Comment: Short answer: no. This is not a driver feature but an SSMS feature. If you want something similar you'd have to write client code to loop through the servers. The CMS feature really doesn't "do" anything on its own other than have a server store lists of other servers. You can retrieve those from `msdb`, should you want (`msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_*`), but you'd still need to query them separately.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ah, dang. I'm currently querying msdb to get the list and looping it through PowerShell for each individual server, but it would have been so much more convenient if querying the CMS directly was possible. :) Thanks so much for your quick reply, I appreciate the answer.